# redis-server /etc/redis.conf just hangs

Tags: redis, amazon-ami

Just installed redis on AWS AMI Linux (RHEL 2018.03) with https://stackoverflow.com/a/34203915/1471267. Running `sudo redis-server` without a config file argument works fine and the server starts as expected. However, if I run `sudo redis-server /etc/redis.conf` then the command just hangs. I've verified that `/etc/redis.conf` does exist and I can't seem to find any sort of verbose mode for `redis-server`.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not hanging. It's just running. You can check with `redis-cli ping`

You can also put redis on background by appending `--daemonize yes`

Comment: You're right. Earlier `redis-cli ping` wasn't returning PONG but it is now.